# Why does this Border doesn´t work anymore?

Tags: java, javafx

Hello I don´t understand why this Border won´t show off. (I tried both versions the one which I changed to a comment and the on over it)

```
public class MyPane extends BorderPane{

private int score=0;

public MyPane() {
    this.score=0;
    init();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
    public void init() {
    BorderPane bp1= new BorderPane();

    Image img=new Image("Ball.png");
    ImageView imv= new ImageView(img);
    imv.setFitHeight(100);
    imv.setFitWidth(100);
    Label label= new Label(Integer.toString(score));
    label.setPrefSize(100, 100);
    label.setFont(new Font(50));
    label.setPadding(new Insets(18));



    HBox hbox= new HBox();
    hbox.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.DARKGREEN, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, null , null)));
    //hbox.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;" + "-fx-border-style: solid inside;"
    //        + "-fx-border-width: 2;" + "-fx-border-insets: 5;"
     //       + "-fx-border-radius: 5;" + "-fx-border-color: blue;");
    hbox.getChildren().add(imv);
    hbox.getChildren().add(label);
    hbox.setSpacing(50);
    hbox.setPadding(new Insets(20));





    bp1.setCenter(hbox);
    this.setTop(bp1);
}
```

}

Comment: I copied you code, with some modifications, into my IDE and executed it—the border rendered appropriately. However, your code is incomplete and contains dependencies not available to us (e.g. the image file). You need to [edit] your question to rework the code into a [mre] demonstrating the issue. Note the example should be _specially created_ for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also, you seem to be complicating things by using an `HBox` here. Read [the documentation of `Label`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Label.html); specifically, the properties that are available (including inherited properties). You can add the `ImageView` to the `Label` directly as a graphic. The gap between the graphic and the text is configurable via another property. And as a `Label` is a `Region` it can have a border set on it.

Comment: Is it now better?

Comment: No, read the content in the link for [MCVE]. At the very least you should include an `Application` class that allows us to run it and in this case also `import` declarations.

Comment: I too cannot reproduce your problem.  What version of Java are you using?  What operating system are you running on?  And are you certain the border is not showing?  It’s at the edges of your pane, so if that pane is the root of a Scene, the border is hard to see.